# Windows7, 'npm start' throws an error when I access the localhost page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows-7, localhost

I use windows 7 64bit. I was following the tutorial ==>docs.angularjs.org/tutorial (https)
I did all in the same way, and when I put 'npm start' in cmd, it seemed to work.

However, if I open Chome browser and try to access ==>localhost:8000/app/index.html (http)
as the tutorial says, I can't access, and gets an error like the following.

[Error is thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EjuW.png)
What is happening?? Wanna know!!

Comment: can you paste the `package.json` here.

Comment: Check out  http://www.alexkras.com/typeerror-the-header-content-contains-invalid-characters/  for similar issue, may be helpful.